# fgets() is not taking the input

Tags: c++, fgets, getline, gets

## Im using  fgets(learner.name,21,stdin) to Input the name of the student but when i run the program ,it shows " Enter your name " and skips to "Enter your marks in 5 subjects. "

## can someone explain me why this happening?Because it is same with cin.getline() function.

## gets_s() function is not working compiler shows " 'gets_s' was not declared in this scope"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
struct Student
{
    int rollno;
    char name[21];
    float marks[5];
    char grade;
};
Student learner ;
int main()
{
    cout<<"\n"<<"Enter Roll number: ";
    cin>>learner.rollno;
    cout<<"\n"<<"Enter your name: ";
    fgets(learner.name,21,stdin);
    cout<<"\n"<<"Enter your marks in 5 subjects: "<<"\n";
    for(int i = 0;i <5;++i)
    {
        cout<<"\n"<<"Subject"<<i+1<<":";
        cin>>learner.marks[i];
    }
    float avg ,total;
    total =  (learner.marks[0]+learner.marks[1]+learner.marks[2]+learner.marks[3]+learner.marks[4]);
    avg = total/5;
    if(avg<50)
        learner.grade = 'D';
    else if(avg<60)
        learner.grade = 'C';
    else if(avg<80) 
        learner.grade = 'B';
    else
        learner.grade = 'A';
    cout<<"\n"<<"\n"<<"Student result: \n";
    cout<<"Roll Number: "<<learner.rollno<<"\t";
    cout<<"Name: ";
    cout.write(learner.name,21);
    cout<<"\n"<<"Total Marks: "<<total;
    cout<<"\t"<<"Grade: "<<learner.grade<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

here is the output:

```
  Enter Roll number: 22
  Enter your name:
  Enter your marks in 5 subjects:

  Subject1:
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to mix formatted I/O   (`cin >> learner.rollno`) with line oriented input (`cin.getline()`)  on the same stream because they handle newlines differently.   The `cin >>rollno` will leave a newline in the stream, waiting to be read, and it will cause `fgets()` or `cin.getline()` to return immediately.    It is also a rather poor idea to mix C I/O (`fgets()`) with C++ stream I/O on the same device (standard input in this case)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction

Comment: So then what do i do ?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that when you type roll no and press enter, `cin` only reads the number, not the newline (this is the default behaviour.). This newline remains in the input stream and when you execute fgets(), it takes in the newline character.
To change this you could use `cin >> noskipws >> learner.rollno;`

Comment: This will not fix the problem unless the user behaves in specific ways .... which are unusual for users.

Comment: It was one of many solutions. (not the best, i agree)

Comment: Your change will affect only the reading of the roll number. A following `fgets` call will still have the same problem.

Comment: I meant to use noskipws for all `cin`

Comment: Regardless of where you apply `noskipws`, how is skipping less whitespace going to help when the problem is extra whitespace? `noskipws` is sticky, so it will affect all future formatted input operations on `cin` anyway. What I meant was that it doesn't affect `fgets` or `getline`.

Comment: Its not working .

Answer (score 0):

`stdin` buffer is not cleared after `cin>>learner.rollno;`, use `getchar()` to clear/flush the `stdin` buffer and then use `cin.getline()` as

```
cin.getline(learner.name,'\n');
```

Comment: It is working now, can you explain me in depth,sir .

Comment: And also when use getchar() after ' cin>>learner.rollno; ', The subject(s) are skipped not taking any input and print the final results . Why ?

Comment: @WILDFIRE once `cin >>rollno` executed, there is a new line left in the `stdin` stream thats why second time when you try to put something into `same stream` its(`stdin` buffer) not clear(previous `\n` is there inside `stdin`). So clear the `stdin` buffer by using `__fpurge(stdin)` or use `getchar()` after every `cin` statement.

Comment: `__fpurge(stdin)` is not portable, you can see it in `man 3 fpurge`, So I suggest you to use `getchar()`

Comment: okay thank you ,sir.